# Slayer exciter not drawing from supply

Tags: transistors, transformer, coil, tesla-coil

I made a Slayer exciter according to the schematic below.

I have done about everything necessary for it to work such as sanding the bottom of the secondary.

I have 2000 turns on secondary, and 7 on primary. I am powering it with 18V DC.  It is powered from my power supply. I notice on my power supply that no current is being drawn from my supply when I power it.

I have an Arduino in the schematic to play music to it.

At the moment the wire going from the Arduino to the actual primary isn't connected in my actual circuit, while it is shown as so in the actual schematic.

Here's the schematic:

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to your schematic, no current flows through the primary. I suspect that the main problem could be due to the number of tip31's in parallel that the base resistor is too high to even start to turn them on. As well, I wonder if there is enough feedback current to turn the transistors off and to overcome the bias of the base resistor.

Comment: I tried decreasing the base resistance to 22k, but it made no difference.

Comment: You *have* used insulated wire on the coils, haven't you?

Comment: @Transistor I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Is your wire insulated or just bare copper? Is there a clear varnish-like coating on it to prevent the turns shorting out?

Comment: @Transistor The primary is aluminum wire while the secondary is copper wire. I have sanded down the ends of both the primary and secondary where they connect to the circuit.

Comment: That's OK then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the tip31c was burned, and the primary was shorting to the secondary.